# Search and Export button on single form in php

Tags: php, redirect, button, submit

I have a form with 2 buttons.I want it to redirect my results on a page called data_results based on the post action from the checkbox selection results.When I click on export it uses that action. My problem is that its doesnt redirect or take the values.

```
<form name="search" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="txtsearch" type="text" />
<select name="searchby" size="1">
<option>Search by</option>
<option value="rule">Rule Number</option>
<option value="pattern_num">Pattern Number</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="btnsearch" value="Search" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" name="btnexport" value="Export" /
<P></P>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="60"><span class="content"><strong>ID</strong></span></td>
    <td width="120" align="center"><strong><span class="content">STAMP</span></strong></td>
    <td width="83" align="center"><span class="content"><strong>RULE</strong></span></td>
    <td width="139"><span class="content"><strong>TEST</strong> <strong>STRING</strong></span></td>
    <td width="90" style="overflow:auto"><span class="content"><strong>TEST</strong> <strong>RESULT</strong></span></td>
    <td width="100%"><span class="content"><strong>TYPE</strong></span></td>
  </tr>
<?php global $database;
$sql="SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY id DESC";
    $result_set = $database->query($sql);
    while ($row=$database->fetch_array($result_set)){
 ?>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr>
 <td width="60" valign="top"><span class="content"><?php echo $row['id']; ?></span></td>
    <td valign="top" width="120" align="right"><span class="content"><?php echo $row['stamp']; ?></span></td>
    <td valign="top" width="139" style="overflow:auto;"><span class="content"><?php echo $row['test_string']; ?></span></td>
    <td valign="top" width="90"><span class="content"><?php echo $row['test_result']; ?></span></td>
    <td valign="top" width="100%"><span class="content"><?php echo $row['type']; ?></span></td>
     <td valign="top" width="50"><span class="content"><input name="check_list[]" type="checkbox" id="check_list[]" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" /></span></td>
  </tr><?php }  ?></form>

</table>
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])) {
    foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $check) {
     $sql="SELECT * FROM tblrules WHERE id={$check}";
    $result_set = $database->query($sql);
    while ($row=$database->fetch_array($result_set)){
        echo "filter {"."<br>";
        echo "\t\t\t\t"."test {"."<br>";
        echo "\t\t\t\t"."type=>".$row['type']."<br>";
        echo "\t\t\t\t"."add_tag => sort_order"."<br>";
            echo "\t"."}"."<br>";
        echo "\t"."}"."<br>";
        }

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: make your export button as ordinary button not submit button. Otherwise it will post data to the form action URL

Comment: when I click on export I want it to take the results of my selection the script to get the selection i added it to the button to give extra explaination

Comment: What is your `print_r($_POST['check_list'])` value? i have one more question you are expecting where it should redirect?

Comment: @Prabu It gives me the record id's I have selected.

Answer (score 0):

To submit with redirection to YourScriptDir/data_results.php please modify the export button code as follows:

```
<input type="submit" 
       name="btnexport" 
       onclick="document.location='http://YourScriptDir/data_results.php';"
       value="Export" />
```

This will work if user browser javascript is enabled, which is the general case nowadays.

Hope this helps...